# SQL: Last_Value() returns wrong result (but First_Value() works fine)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-function

I have a table in SQL Server 2012 as the snapshot shows:

[image]

Then I'm using Last_Value() and First Value to get AverageAmount of each EmpID for different YearMonth. The script is as follows:

```
SELECT A.EmpID,  
       First_Value(A.AverageAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EmpID Order by A.DimYearMonthKey asc) AS  '200901AvgAmount', 
       Last_Value(A.AverageAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EmpID Order by A.DimYearMonthKey asc) AS '201112AvgAmount'

FROM  Emp_Amt  AS A
```

However, the result for this query is:

[image: result]

In column of "201112AvgAmount", it shows different values for each EmpID while "200901AvgAmount" has correct values.

Is there anything wrong with my SQL script? I did a lot research online but still cannot find the answer....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your script, this is a way how partitioning works in SQL server :/. If you change LAST_VALUE to MAX result will be the same. Solution would be:

```
SELECT A.EmpID,  
       First_Value(A.AverageAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EmpID Order by A.DimYearMonthKey asc) AS  '200901AvgAmount', 
       Last_Value(A.AverageAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EmpID Order by A.DimYearMonthKey ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS '201112AvgAmount'  
FROM  Emp_Amt  AS A
```

There is a great post about it, [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/09/sql-server-introduction-to-first-_value-and-last_value-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/). GL!

Comment: Thank you soooooo much! Not only solved the problem but also tells me why. I browsed the linked post previously but did not think about mechanism of partitioning.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a quick query to illustrate the behaviour:

```
select 
  v,

  -- FIRST_VALUE() and LAST_VALUE()
  first_value(v) over(order by v) f1,
  first_value(v) over(order by v rows between unbounded preceding and current row) f2,
  first_value(v) over(order by v rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) f3,
  last_value (v) over(order by v) l1,
  last_value (v) over(order by v rows between unbounded preceding and current row) l2,
  last_value (v) over(order by v rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) l3,

  -- For completeness' sake, let's also compare the above with MAX()
  max        (v) over() m1,
  max        (v) over(order by v) m2,
  max        (v) over(order by v rows between unbounded preceding and current row) m3,
  max        (v) over(order by v rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) m4
from (values(1),(2),(3),(4)) t(v)
```

The output of the above query can be seen here ([SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/22802)):

```
| V | F1 | F2 | F3 | L1 | L2 | L3 | M1 | M2 | M3 | M4 |
|---|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|----|
| 1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  4 |  4 |  1 |  1 |  4 |
| 2 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  2 |  2 |  4 |  4 |  2 |  2 |  4 |
| 3 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  3 |  3 |  4 |  4 |  3 |  3 |  4 |
| 4 |  1 |  1 |  1 |  4 |  4 |  4 |  4 |  4 |  4 |  4 |
```

Few people think of the implicit frames that are applied to window functions that take an `ORDER BY` clause. In this case, windows are defaulting to the frame `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. (RANGE is not exactly the same as ROWS, but that's another story). Think about it this way:

- On the row with `v = 1` the ordered window's frame spans `v IN (1)`
- On the row with `v = 2` the ordered window's frame spans `v IN (1, 2)`
- On the row with `v = 3` the ordered window's frame spans `v IN (1, 2, 3)`
- On the row with `v = 4` the ordered window's frame spans `v IN (1, 2, 3, 4)`

If you want to prevent that behaviour, you have two options:

- Use an explicit `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` clause for *ordered* window functions
- Use no `ORDER BY` clause in those window functions that allow for omitting them (as `MAX(v) OVER()`)

More details are explained in [this article about `LEAD()`, `LAG()`, `FIRST_VALUE()` and `LAST_VALUE()`](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/11/07/dont-miss-out-on-awesome-sql-power-with-first_value-last_value-lead-and-lag/)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is repeat your query using first_value, just make order as asc for 1st case and desc for 2nd case.

```
SELECT A.EmpID,  
       First_Value(A.AverageAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EmpID Order by A.DimYearMonthKey asc) AS  '200901AvgAmount', 
       First_Value(A.AverageAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY A.EmpID Order by A.DimYearMonthKey desc) AS '201112AvgAmount'

FROM  Emp_Amt  AS A
```