# LAST_VALUE in SQL Server 2012 is returning weird results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am having a weird result when I am trying to get the LAST_VALUE from a table in SQL Server 2012.

This is the table I have

```
PK | Id1 | Id2
1  | 2   | 5
2  | 2   | 6
3  | 2   | 5
4  | 2   | 6
```

This is my query

```
SELECT
    Id1, Id2, LAST_VALUE(PK) OVER (PARTITION BY Id1 ORDER BY Id2) AS LastValue
FROM
    @Data
```

This is the result I am expecting

```
Id1 | Id2  | LastValue
2   | 5    | 3
2   | 5    | 3
2   | 6    | 4
2   | 6    | 4
```

This is what I am receiving

```
Id1 | Id2  | LastValue
2   | 5    | 3
2   | 5    | 3
2   | 6    | 2
2   | 6    | 2
```

Here is a demonstration of the problem
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c729/1

Is there anything wrong with my query?

Comment: Why are you expecting those values?, both are valid, because the order is being done by `Id2`, so it chooses one of them

Comment: You are right, both solutions are valid.  I was expecting that order because it is the order which the data was inserted in the table.  I think I am mixing concepts and I have to use MAX instead of LAST_VALUE to get what I am looking for.

Comment: Because the result is not the expected.  You can check the result returned with your order here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c729/9

Comment: So do you actually want the last value according to the order? Or do you want a max value?

Comment: In this case, I need the MAX value but I had another case where I need the last inserted value.   In the case I need the last inserted value (the question apply for that case), I don't know how to change the query to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't know or care about the order in which rows were inserted into the table. If you need specific order, always use `ORDER BY`. In your example `ORDER BY` is ambiguous, unless you include `PK` into the `ORDER BY`. Besides, `LAST_VALUE` function can return odd results if you are not careful - see below.

You can get your expected result using `MAX` or `LAST_VALUE` ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c729/24/0)). They are equivalent in this case:

```
SELECT
    PK, Id1, Id2
    ,MAX(PK) OVER (PARTITION BY Id1, Id2) AS MaxValue
    ,LAST_VALUE(PK) OVER (PARTITION BY Id1, Id2 ORDER BY PK rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) AS LastValue
FROM
    Data
ORDER BY id1, id2, PK
```

Result of this query will be the same regardless of the order in which rows were originally inserted into the table. You can try to put `INSERT` statements in different order in the fiddle. It doesn't affect the result.

Also, `LAST_VALUE` behaves not quite as you'd intuitively expect with default window (when you have just `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause). Default window is `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`, while you'd expected it to be `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`. Here is a SO answer with a [good explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388892/sql-last-value-returns-wrong-result-but-first-value-works-fine/26806428#26806428). The link to this SO answer is on MSDN page for [`LAST_VALUE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517.aspx). So, once the row window is specified explicitly in the query it returns what is needed.

---

If you want to know the order in which rows were inserted into the table, I think, the most simple way is to use [`IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx). So, definition of your table would change to this:

```
CREATE TABLE Data 
(PK INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Id1 INT,
Id2 INT)
```

When you `INSERT` into this table you don't need to specify the value for `PK`, the server would generate it automatically. It guarantees that generated values are unique and growing (with positive increment parameter), even if you have many clients inserting into the table at the same time simultaneously. There may be gaps between generated values, but the relative order of the generated values will tell you which row was inserted after which row.

Answer (score 1):

> It is never a good idea to rely on implicit order caused by the particular implementation of the underlying database engine.

I don't know why, running the query

```
SELECT * FROM @Data ORDER BY Id2
```

the result will be

```
+----+-----+-----+
| PK | id1 | id2 |
+----+-----+-----+
|  1 |   2 |   5 |
|  3 |   2 |   5 |
|  4 |   2 |   6 |
|  2 |   2 |   6 |
+----+-----+-----+
```

which means SQL Server decided the order of rows in a way that is different from the insert order.

That's why the `LAST_VALUE` behavior is different from expected, but is consistent with the SQL Server sort method.

**But how SQL Server sort your data?**

The best answer we have is the accepted answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040724/how-does-sql-server-sort-your-data) (from where I took the sentence in the beginning of my answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Id1
        , Id2
        , LAST_VALUE(PK) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY Id1 
            ORDER BY Id2 DESC) AS LastValue
FROM    Data
ORDER BY Id2 ASC
```

**Result**

```
Id1 Id2 LastValue
2   5   3
2   5   3
2   6   4
2   6   4
```