# last_value partition

Tags: sql

```
Select speed, ram, price, 
       last_value(price) over (partition by speed, ram order by speed, ram) as lastp 
from PC
```

---

PC table

```
code    model   speed   ram  hd     cd  price

 1      1232    500     64   5.0    12x 600.0000
 10     1260    500     32   10.0   12x 350.0000
 11     1233    900     128  40.0   40x 980.0000
 12     1233    800     128  20.0   50x 970.0000
 2      1121    750     128  14.0   40x 850.0000
 3      1233    500     64   5.0    12x 600.0000
 4      1121    600     128  14.0   40x 850.0000
 5      1121    600     128  8.0    40x 850.0000
 6      1233    750     128  20.0   50x 950.0000
 7      1232    500     32   10.0   12x 400.0000
 8      1232    450     64   8.0    24x 350.0000
 9      1232    450     32   10.0   24x 350.0000
```

```
speed   ram price       lastp

450     32  350.0000    350.0000
450     64  350.0000    350.0000
500     32  350.0000    350.0000
500     32  400.0000    350.0000
```

Can anyone explain why in speed 500 ram 32 lastp is 350 not 400

Comment: Because in the window you have, your last value for price is 350. Try to run `ROW_NUMBER` over it to see which one is the last row you get per partition

Comment: interesting..i did that and it appears the last value for price is indead 350 not 400, how come? I thought it was already grouped so the last value for price is 400

Comment: Maybe in your `ORDER BY`, you need to make `speed DESC`

Comment: i dont think thats the case how can 350 be last row and 400 be first...makes no sense since its group by speed and then ram

Comment: It would be useful if you can provide some sample data before windowing your result set.

Comment: `LAST_VALUE` can return unexpected results if you are not careful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388892/sql-last-value-returns-wrong-result-but-first-value-works-fine/26806428#26806428 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971151/last-value-in-sql-server-2012-is-returning-weird-results

Answer (score 1):

You can make another query based on the main one. I don't know your dbms, but you can try this in most databases.

```
;WITH C AS(
Select speed, ram, price,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by speed, ram order by speed, ram) as Rn
from tbl
)
SELECT speed, ram, price
  ,LAST_VALUE(price) over (partition by speed, ram order by speed , ram) as lastp
  FROM C
ORDER BY speed, ram, Rn DESC
```

[SQLFiddle for SQL Server](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5eb4c/17)